# What can causes "Too many connection" for Hibernate 4

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

I'm using Hibernate 4 and mysql for my current website, after I tried to keep refreshing the page many time in 2 web browser's tab, the server gone down with error log:

```
ERROR: Data source rejected establishment of connection,  message from server: "Too many connections"
org.hibernate.exception.JDBCConnectionException: Could not open connection
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.SQLExceptionTypeDelegate.convert(SQLExceptionTypeDelegate.java:68)
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:49)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:125)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:110)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionImpl.obtainConnection(LogicalConnectionImpl.java:304)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionImpl.getConnection(LogicalConnectionImpl.java:169)
    at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.jdbc.JdbcTransaction.doBegin(JdbcTransaction.java:67)
    at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.spi.AbstractTransactionImpl.begin(AbstractTransactionImpl.java:160)
    at hibernate.dao.StockDao.getWarehouseInStock(StockDao.java:132)
    at Utils.Common.updateStockHistorical(Common.java:501)
    at Controller.StockServlet.processRequest(StockServlet.java:67)
    at Controller.StockServlet.doPost(StockServlet.java:116)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:637)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at Controller.ServletFilter.doFilter(ServletFilter.java:134)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:293)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11AprProcessor.process(Http11AprProcessor.java:879)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11AprProtocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11AprProtocol.java:600)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$Worker.run(AprEndpoint.java:1703)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLNonTransientConnectionException: Data source rejected establishment of connection,  message from server: "Too many connections"
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedConstructorAccessor70.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:525)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:411)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:386)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1014)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:988)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:974)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.doHandshake(MysqlIO.java:1104)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.coreConnect(ConnectionImpl.java:2412)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.connectOneTryOnly(ConnectionImpl.java:2445)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:2230)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.<init>(ConnectionImpl.java:813)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection.<init>(JDBC4Connection.java:47)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedConstructorAccessor62.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:525)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:411)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:399)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:334)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:579)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:190)
    at org.hibernate.service.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.getConnection(DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.java:173)
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSessionImpl$NonContextualJdbcConnectionAccess.obtainConnection(AbstractSessionImpl.java:279)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionImpl.obtainConnection(LogicalConnectionImpl.java:297)
    ... 24 more
```

And this is my config for hibernate:

```
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN" "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
  <session-factory>
    <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/wstrader2?characterEncoding=UTF-8</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.username">root</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.password">root</property>
    <property name="hibernate.current_session_context_class">jta</property>
    <mapping resource="hibernate/dto/Warehouse.hbm.xml"/>
    <mapping resource="hibernate/dto/Exchange.hbm.xml"/>
    <mapping resource="hibernate/dto/Packing.hbm.xml"/>
    <mapping resource="hibernate/dto/GradeMaster.hbm.xml"/>
    <mapping resource="hibernate/dto/MarketFobDiff.hbm.xml"/>
    <mapping resource="hibernate/dto/Arbitration.hbm.xml"/>
    <mapping resource="hibernate/dto/Quality.hbm.xml"/>
    <mapping resource="hibernate/dto/Region.hbm.xml"/>
    <mapping resource="hibernate/dto/City.hbm.xml"/>
    <mapping resource="hibernate/dto/Contract.hbm.xml"/>
    <mapping resource="hibernate/dto/HistoricalBasis.hbm.xml"/>
    <mapping resource="hibernate/dto/Country.hbm.xml"/>
    <mapping resource="hibernate/dto/Origin.hbm.xml"/>
    <mapping resource="hibernate/dto/WarehouseReceipt.hbm.xml"/>
    <mapping resource="hibernate/dto/DailyBasis.hbm.xml"/>
    <mapping resource="hibernate/dto/User.hbm.xml"/>
    <mapping resource="hibernate/dto/Movement.hbm.xml"/>
    <mapping resource="hibernate/dto/PaymentTerm.hbm.xml"/>
    <mapping resource="hibernate/dto/ContractTerm.hbm.xml"/>
    <mapping resource="hibernate/dto/CompanyMaster.hbm.xml"/>
    <mapping resource="hibernate/dto/ProcessingOrder.hbm.xml"/>
    <mapping resource="hibernate/dto/Stock.hbm.xml"/>
    <mapping resource="hibernate/dto/HistoricalStock.hbm.xml"/>
    <mapping resource="hibernate/dto/Menu.hbm.xml"/>
    <mapping resource="hibernate/dto/Authorization.hbm.xml"/>
    <mapping resource="hibernate/dto/Page.hbm.xml"/>
    <mapping resource="hibernate/dto/ContractPriceFixation.hbm.xml"/>
    <mapping resource="hibernate/dto/FuturesContract.hbm.xml"/>
    <mapping resource="hibernate/dto/FutureCloseOut.hbm.xml"/>
    <mapping resource="hibernate/dto/Currency.hbm.xml"/>
    <mapping resource="hibernate/dto/FuturesContractArchive.hbm.xml"/>
    <mapping resource="hibernate/dto/FutureCloseOutArchive.hbm.xml"/>
    <mapping resource="hibernate/dto/ScreenMaster.hbm.xml"/>
    <mapping resource="hibernate/dto/QualityMaster.hbm.xml"/>
  </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

And here is my HibernateUtil.java:

```
public class HibernateUtil {
    private static final SessionFactory ourSessionFactory;
    private static ServiceRegistry serviceRegistry;
    private static Configuration configuration = new Configuration().configure();

    static {
        try {
            serviceRegistry = new ServiceRegistryBuilder().applySettings(
                    configuration.getProperties()).buildServiceRegistry();
            ourSessionFactory = configuration.buildSessionFactory(serviceRegistry);
        } catch (Throwable ex) {
            throw new ExceptionInInitializerError(ex);
        }
    }

    public static Session getSession() throws HibernateException {
        return ourSessionFactory.openSession();
    }
}
```

Could someone find out the reason or tell me the conditions cause error `"Too many connection"`, and `org.hibernate.exception.JDBCConnectionException: Could not open connection`
I try to find related topics but still not found the answer for my problem

Thanks for reading this topic.

**UPDATED**:
my sample Dao.java:

```
public class CityDAO {

    private Session session = null;

    public CityDAO() {
        session = HibernateUtil.getSession();
    }

    public ArrayList<City> getAllCities() {
        try {
            session.getTransaction().begin();
            Criteria crit = session.createCriteria(City.class);
            ArrayList<City> cities = (ArrayList<City>)crit.list();
            session.flush();
            session.getTransaction().commit();
            return cities;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            if (session.getTransaction().isActive()) {
                session.getTransaction().rollback();
            }
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    public City getCityById(int id){
        try {
            session.getTransaction().begin();
            Criteria crit = session.createCriteria(City.class);
            crit.add(Restrictions.eq("id", id));
            City city = (City)crit.uniqueResult();
            session.flush();
            session.getTransaction().commit();
            return city;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            if (session.getTransaction().isActive()) {
                session.getTransaction().rollback();
            }
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Try to setup a c3p0 config: http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/session-configuration.html

Comment: Each DB has its own connections limit. In this case this is exactly that restriction. It seems, that your connection pool is set up incorrectly: it must have max connections  <= max connections of DB

Comment: You should use connection pool in production environment, as PeterMmm say. And how you manage transactions and when close hibernate session?

Comment: @user1516873: OK, let me update a sample DAO for easier viewing what I do. I you can, please give me an advise in my system design, thanks :)

Comment: @Azzurri difficult question. If you don't use Lazy Loading, and commit at the end of every DAO method, You can easy replace that behavior with Spring `@Transactional` interface. It gives you clean transaction demarcation and right hibernate session open/close/commit/rollback pattern. Your DAO and Service layer also will be simpler with `@Autowire`. As disadvantage - you should use Spring framework, with its own context, annotations, configs and so on.

Comment: @Azzurri but if you use Lazy Loading, i think you should read documentation, section Unit of Work. http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/transactions.html#transactions-basics-uow

Answer (score 2):

I found solution for my problem.
Because my web application use servlet - the old fashioned one. So I try this:

https://community.jboss.org/wiki/OpenSessionInView

And it's work for me.

Thanks you guys for give me advices :D

Answer (score 0):

I assume, that the exception is thrown by MySql. Either you increase the maxconnections there or you check your source if there is a resource leak. For example, don't create connections instances each request or close the connection after every request and so on.

Answer (score 0):

You have one open session on every instance of your DAO class, and even if you set up connection pool, it will not much help.

You made something like *many-sessions-per-application* anti-pattern (a bit different of [*session-per-application*](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.1/devguide/en-US/html_single/#d5e626)). That anti-pattern has problems, described in [Hiberhate Guide](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.1/devguide/en-US/html_single/#transactions-basics-issues)

> A Session is not thread-safe. Things that work concurrently, like HTTP
> requests, session beans, or Swing workers, will cause race conditions
> if a Session instance is shared.
>
> An exception thrown by Hibernate means you have to rollback your
> database transaction and close the Session immediately

Additional, because you haven't connection pool, application cannot detect situation, when connection was killed by server.